Solana: Run maliscous code / InvalidAccountForFee / wallet isnt functioning anymore
before I start:
yes I know I was stupid
yes, I am guilty myself
yes i deserve this as punishment
yes i am still trying to fix the problem.
Problem: i tried a mev bot code for pumpo.fun on solana and fell for a pretty clever but at the same time stupid farmer scam.
I executed the code https://github.com/TheMisterFrog/pumpfun-mevbot/commit/e6cab0567fcfca1d182959d5aaffee77b5869638
since then my wallet is not able to execute any transaction. Is there any way to undo this? sometimes it shows the error: InvalidAccountForFee.
I am grateful for any help

I already tried solandys tool but didn t fucntion

The title isn't quite understandable would be good to narrow down title to the exact problem you're facing

and if you could send your wallet address would be helpful

The wallet is :5fEPo2NPB3tnLrWRnzoP6ZoRWpH79t1LhQnVEgrePRD1
